# Booting in insecure mode

Tags: 14.04

I've upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 and getting the message 'booting in insecure mode' after turning my computer on and also my system's performance has drop down compare to Ubuntu 14.04, it is processing comparably slow to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I disagree with that advice, non-LTS are supported.

Comment: Secure boot is enabled or disabled in your BIOS. You can boot with or without it enabled, your choice. You need to disable secure boot with proprietary , non signed drivers such as nvidia and ati (last I looked)

Comment: is it safe to boot in insecure mode

Comment: what about the performance, i am getting a slower performance in it.

Comment: safe mode should not directly affect performance, the only possible effect would be open vs closed source driver. secure boot offers additional security by confirming your drivers are signed, and if the signature is off or unsigned, it will not boot. With that said, it adds more to Windows then linux as the linux drivers are not all signed and linux security is different from windows.

Comment: You could remove this message by booting directly from `grubx64.efi` instead of `shimx64.efi`. But it's not a major issue and unless you want to dig deeper into EFI, leave it as it is would be the safest option.

Comment: On my system, secure boot is completely separate from UEFI